# Firebase data retrieval issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue with retrieving data from my Firebase database. Please excuse my lack of technial speech as this is not my strong point.
My application is to create a Vehicle listing which posts to a page with a RecyclerView. A new vehicle is added via the "NewVehicle.class" and saved to Firebase underneath an automatically generated node. The user can select a vehicle from the "VehicleList.class" this re-directs them to the "PasswordProtected.class". The user needs to enter a password to view the data relating to the vehicle. Both the vehicle and the "PasswordProtected.class" are linked, or in other words the code knows which vehicle to look at in the database. The user is redirected to the "DataDisplay.class" where they can choose from the graphs they want to view. The issue i am having now is retrieving the specific "VehiclesData" from one vehicle and displaying them in the graph. i have also added an image of what my database looks like in firebase.

[image]

NewVehicle.class

```
public class NewVehicle extends AppCompatActivity
{
//XML variables
private ImageView newVehicleImage;
private EditText vehicleMake, vehicleModel, vehicleReg, password, con_password, engineSize;
private ProgressDialog progress;

private Uri vehicleImage = null;

private StorageReference storageRef;
private DatabaseReference databaseRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_vehicle);

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vehicles");

    newVehicleImage = findViewById(R.id.new_vehicle_image);
    vehicleMake =  findViewById(R.id.new_vehicle_make);
    vehicleModel =  findViewById(R.id.new_vehicle_model);
    vehicleReg =  findViewById(R.id.new_vehicle_reg);
    engineSize =  findViewById(R.id.new_vehicle_engine);
    Button vehicleAdd = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    con_password = findViewById(R.id.con_password);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    newVehicleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setMinCropResultSize(512, 512)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(NewVehicle.this);
        }
    });

    //When user selects the 'Add' button
    vehicleAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            StartPosting();
        }
    });

}//End onCreate()

private void StartPosting()
{
    progress.setMessage("Posting to Vehicle list");

    //The make, model and reg is saved to Strings
    final String make = vehicleMake.getText().toString().trim();
    final String model = vehicleModel.getText().toString().trim();
    final String reg = vehicleReg.getText().toString().trim();
    final String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
    final String engine = engineSize.getText().toString().trim();
    final String con_pass = con_password.getText().toString().trim();

    //If the password length is less than six
    if(con_pass.length()<6)
    {
        con_password.setError(getText(R.string.mini_length));
        con_password.requestFocus();
    }

    if(pass.length()<6)
    {
        password.setError(getText(R.string.mini_length));
        password.requestFocus();
    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(make) &&  !TextUtils.isEmpty(model) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(reg) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(engine) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(con_pass) && vehicleImage != null)
    {
        if (pass.equals(con_pass))
        {
            progress.show();

            StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("vehicle_images").child(vehicleImage.getLastPathSegment());

            filePath.putFile(vehicleImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newpost = databaseRef.push();

                    newpost.child("Make").setValue(make);
                    newpost.child("Model").setValue(model);
                    newpost.child("Reg").setValue(reg);
                    newpost.child("Password").setValue(pass);
                    newpost.child("Engine").setValue(engine);
                    newpost.child("Confirmed_Password").setValue(con_pass);
                    newpost.child("Image").setValue(Objects.requireNonNull(downloadUrl).toString());

                    progress.dismiss();

                    startActivity(new Intent(NewVehicle.this, VehicleList.class));
                }
            });
        }

        if (!pass.equals(con_pass))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords must match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be left empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            vehicleImage = result.getUri();
            newVehicleImage.setImageURI(vehicleImage);
        }
        //If the resultCode has an error
        else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
        {
            Toast.makeText(NewVehicle.this, "Application Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}//End NewVehicle()
```

VehicleList.class

```
public class VehicleList extends AppCompatActivity
{
//Declaring RecyclerView
private RecyclerView vehicleList;
//Declaring DatabaseReference to FireBase
private DatabaseReference databaseRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Sets the layout according to the XML file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle_list);

    //Linking to the FireBase Real-time Database
    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vehicles");

    //XML variable
    vehicleList = findViewById(R.id.vehicle_list_view);
    vehicleList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    vehicleList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FloatingActionButton addVehicleBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_vehicle_btn);

    //If the user taps the addPostBtn
    addVehicleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //They will be redirected to the 'NewPost' class where they can add a new post
            Intent intent = new Intent(VehicleList.this, NewVehicle.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }//End onClick()
    });//End addVehicleBtn()
}//End onCreate()

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    //Recycler Adapter for Vehicles
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VehicleLog, VehicleViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VehicleLog, VehicleViewHolder>(
            VehicleLog.class,
            R.layout.vehicle_itemlist,
            VehicleViewHolder.class,
            databaseRef
    ){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(VehicleViewHolder viewHolder, VehicleLog model, int position)
        {
            //Get the unique identifier for each record in the database
            final String vehicle_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            //Gathers the data
            viewHolder.setMakeText(model.getMake());
            viewHolder.setModelText(model.getModel());
            viewHolder.setRegText(model.getReg());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

            //If a record is tapped on
            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //Users redirected to the next screen
                    Intent intent = new Intent(VehicleList.this, PasswordProtected.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Vehicle_id", vehicle_key);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }//End onClick()
            });//End OnClickListener()
        }//End populateViewHolder()
    };//End FirebaseRecyclerAdapter()

    vehicleList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}//End onStart()

public static class VehicleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    public VehicleViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }//End VehicleViewHolder()

    //Sets the vehicles make on screen
    public void setMakeText(String make)
    {
        TextView vehicle_make = mView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_make);
        vehicle_make.setText(make);
    }//End setMakeText()

    //Sets the vehicles model on screen
    public void setModelText(String model)
    {
        TextView vehicle_model = mView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_model);
        vehicle_model.setText(model);
    }//End setModelText()

    //Sets the vehicles reg on screen
    public void setRegText(String reg)
    {
        TextView vehicle_reg = mView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_reg);
        vehicle_reg.setText(reg);
    }//End setRegText()

    //Sets the vehicles image on screen using Glide
    public void setImage(Context ctx, String Image)
    {
        ImageView vehicle_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Glide.with(ctx).load(Image).into(vehicle_image);
    }//End setImage()
}//End VehicleViewHolder()
}
```

PasswordProtected.class

```
public class PasswordProtected extends AppCompatActivity
{
//Declaring XML variables
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView vehicle_make, vehicle_model;
private EditText ent_pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_protected);

    vehicle_model = findViewById(R.id.model);
    vehicle_make = findViewById(R.id.make);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);

    Button cont = findViewById(R.id.cont);
    ent_pass = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vehicles");

    //Gathers the unique key of each record in the database
    String vehicle_key = 
Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("Vehicle_id");


 databaseRef.child(Objects.requireNonNull(vehicle_key))
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            String model = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Model").getValue();
            String make = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Make").getValue();
            String image = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue();

            vehicle_model.setText(model);
            vehicle_make.setText(make);
            Glide.with(PasswordProtected.this).load(image).into(imageView);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            Toast.makeText(PasswordProtected.this, "Database Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final String enter_pass = ent_pass.getText().toString().trim();

            final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vehicles");

            String vehicle_key = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString("Vehicle_id");
            databaseRef.child(Objects.requireNonNull(vehicle_key)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String pass = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Password").getValue();

                    Log.v("Firebase:", pass);

                    if(Objects.equals(pass, enter_pass))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PasswordProtected.this, DataDisplay.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"PASSWORD DONT MATCH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }//End else()
                }//End onDataChange()

                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PasswordProtected.this, "Database Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            if(enter_pass.isEmpty())
            {
                ent_pass.setError(getText(R.string.pass_empt));
                ent_pass.requestFocus();
            }

            if(enter_pass.length()<6)
            {
                ent_pass.setError(getText(R.string.mini_length));
                ent_pass.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

DisplayData.class

```
public class DataDisplay extends AppCompatActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_display);

    //XML variables
    Button mass_air = findViewById(R.id.mass_air);
    Button engine_load = findViewById(R.id.engine_throttle);
    Button engine_RPM = findViewById(R.id.RPM);
    Button engine_temps = findViewById(R.id.engine_temps);

    mass_air.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DataDisplay.this, GraphEngineAirflow.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    engine_temps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DataDisplay.this, GraphTempSpecs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    engine_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DataDisplay.this, GraphEngineSpecs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    engine_RPM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DataDisplay.this, GraphEngineRPM.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

GraphEngineAirflow.class

```
public class GraphEngineAirflow extends Activity implements
    OnChartGestureListener, OnChartValueSelectedListener
{
private static final String TAG = "GraphEngineAirflow";

private LineChart chart;

//Array to hold Mass Airflow data from Firebase
ArrayList<Entry> engineAirflow = new ArrayList<>();

//Variables
LineDataSet set1;
LineData data;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /*This creates an Alert dialog on this screen, it also sets it so the user can cancel the message
      for the Mass Airflow rate information*/
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GraphEngineAirflow.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    //Setting the title and message from the string.xml
    builder.setTitle(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.engine_airflow_title));
    builder.setMessage(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.engine_airflow_def));

    //When the user selects the Cancel button the page will redirect back to the VehicleSpec page
    builder.setNegativeButton(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(GraphEngineAirflow.this, DataDisplay.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }//End onClick()
    });//End setNegativeButton()

    builder.setPositiveButton(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {

        }//End onClick()
    });//End setPositiveButton()

    builder.show();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Sets the layout according to the XML file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_engine_airflow);

    //XML reference
    chart = findViewById(R.id.linechart);

    //Listens for on chart taps
    chart.setOnChartGestureListener(GraphEngineAirflow.this);
    chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(GraphEngineAirflow.this);

    //Enable touch gestures
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    //Enable scaling and dragging
    chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    //Enable pinch zoom
    chart.setPinchZoom(true);

    //Background color
    chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    //Setting YAxis
    YAxis left = chart.getAxisLeft();
    left.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    left.setAxisMaximum(50f);
    left.setTextSize(13f);
    left.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);

    YAxis left2 = chart.getAxisRight();
    left2.setEnabled(false);

    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    //Value string
    String[] vals = new String[] {"0s", "1s", "2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "10s", "11s"};

    //Legend object
    Legend i = chart.getLegend();
    //Customise legend
    i.setTextSize(15f);
    i.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
    i.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    //Setting XAis
    XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
    x.setTextSize(13f);
    x.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(vals));
    x.setGranularity(1);
    x.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    //Adding value to array as system will crash without
    engineAirflow.add(new Entry(0, 0));
    engineAirflow.add(new Entry(1, 0));

    //Setting the line
    set1 = new LineDataSet(engineAirflow, "Engine AirFlow ");
    set1.setFillAlpha(110);
    set1.setColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setLineWidth(3f);
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    data = new LineData(set1);

    chart.setData(data);

    //Calls the downloadDatt()
    downloadData();
    //Change the chart when a change occurs
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //XML button
    Button checkD = findViewById(R.id.checkdata);

    //If the user taps the button
    checkD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            /*This creates an Alert dialog on this screen, it also sets it so the user can cancel the message
            for the Mass Airflow rate information retrieved from the database*/
            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(GraphEngineAirflow.this);
            builder2.setCancelable(true);

            //Setting the title and message from the string.xml
            builder2.setTitle(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.IMPORTANT));
            builder2.setMessage(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.airflow_info));

            //When the user selects the Cancel button the page will redirect back to the VehicleSpec page
            builder2.setNegativeButton(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GraphEngineAirflow.this, DataDisplay.class);
                    startActivity(intent); }//End onClick()
            });//End setNegativeButton()

            //If the user taps Ok
            builder2.setPositiveButton(GraphEngineAirflow.this.getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }//End onClick()
            });//End setPositiveButton()

            //Show the Dialogs on screen
            builder2.show();
        }//End onClick()
    });//End OnClickListener()
}//End onCreate

//Downloads Data from FireBase
private void downloadData()
{
    //ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.activity_graph_engine_airflow);

    //Connecting into table "VehicleData" on the FireBase database
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vehicles");

    //ChildEventListener allows child events to be listened for
    database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey)
        {
            //Holds the DataSnapshot value of the database as type String
            VehicleData vehicleData = dataSnapshot.getValue(VehicleData.class);

            //Prints values to console to prove the download is working
            System.out.println("getmassAirflowRate: " + Objects.requireNonNull(vehicleData).getMassAirflowRate());
            System.out.println("prevChildKey: " + prevChildKey);
            System.out.println("data.key" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

            //Converting value to integer
            setData(Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getKey()), vehicleData);

            //Will refresh app when the data changes in the database
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }//End onChildAdded()

        //Will run when data within the database is changed/edited
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
        {

        }//End onChildChanged()

        //Will run when data within the database is removed
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {

        }//End onChildRemoved()

        //Will run when data within the database is moved to different location
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
        {

        }//End onChildMoved()

        //Will run when any sort of error occurs
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }//End onCancelled()
    });//End addChildEventListener()
}//End DownloadData()

//Function sets the data on the graph
private void setData(int key, VehicleData vehicleData)
{
    //Prints to console first
    System.out.println("Using key: " + key);
    System.out.println("Setting Mass Intake Airflow Rate: " + vehicleData.getMassAirflowRate());

    //Adds new entries to the arrayList and converts the string into a float
    engineAirflow.add(new Entry(key + 2, Float.parseFloat(vehicleData.getMassAirflowRate())));

    //Change the chart when changes occurs
    set1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    data.notifyDataChanged();
    this.chart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Redisplay chart
    chart.invalidate();
}//End setData()

//Using the String to change the values of the XAis
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter
{
    private String[] mVals;
    private MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] vals)
    {
        this.mVals = vals;
    }//End MyXAxisValueFormatter()

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis)
    {
        return mVals[(int)value];
    }//End getFormattedValue()

}//End MyXAxisValueFormatter()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartGestureStart: X:" + me.getX() + "Y:" + me.getY());
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartGestureEnd: " + lastPerformedGesture);
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartLongPressed: ");
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartDoubleTapped: ");
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartSingleTapped: ");
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartFling: veloX: " + velocityX + "veloY" + velocityY);
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartScale: ScaleX: " + scaleX + "ScaleY: " + scaleY);
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onChartTranslate: dX" + dX + "dY" + dY);
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, "onValueSelected: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}//End()

@Override
//Sends log message if action is performed
public void onNothingSelected() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onNothingSelected: ");
}//End()

}//End GraphEngineAirflow()
```

Comment: `.child("Vehicle data");` has space in it firebase doesn't allow spaces for keys use `.child("VehicleData");` may be thats the issue

Comment: add your app logcat  too, to question

Comment: Also where are you passing the vehicle_id in the intent which you are getting in your new code ?

Comment: @UmarHussain Hi yes, i changed it to .child("VehiclesData"); however no joy

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vehicles").child(vehicle_key).child("Vehicle data");
```

to,

```
 DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vehicles").child(vehicle_key).child("VehiclesData");
```

Your code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your First case use reference like this (Not at root directory)

```
 DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VehicleData").child(your id here mean 0 1 2 how you set that simillarly get as it (check if is not null first) );
```

you are not referencing to the 0 1 2 3 ids thats mean under the root directory of Vehicle Data you get complete child as value which is not a valid class of VehicleData Class. So you need to move to 0 1 2 3 under which you have a complete class of Vehicle Data

Comment: okay but in my previous code i did not have to reference to 0,1,2,3,4 :     
     DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("VehicleData");  and this code worked by retrieving massAirflowValue from each node

Comment: how did you get that value can you post ? and post the logcat too brother